# Gen 25:22 running fight over two worlds

Tags: commentaries, parashat-toldot

Looking at Bereshit/Genesis 25:22

Some commentators [based on the Midrash of Genesis Rabbah 63:6] offer a  explanation [of “Vayitrotzatzu: and they struggled”] as having the meaning of “ratz/rutz: running.”  When Rivkah would pass by a place of Torah study (Beit Knesset, Tefillah, Midrash) [of Shem and Ever], Ya'akov would run and push to come out.  When she would pass by a place of an idol worship or wordly place, Esav would run and push to come out.

Rashi presents another explanation in which the two boys fought over two worlds (Olam Hazeh and the Olam Habah).

It seems those kind of commentaries present a twofold: one side (spiritual) v.s. another side (earthly) represented in the characters, running and the two worlds.

What I would like to know though is why then the two boys fought over both worlds?

Comment: The Lubavitcher Rebbe addresses this question, together with another question (how can someone be wicked in the womb), in Likkutei Sichot volume 20 (Parshat Toldot page 108). Here are some english summaries of that sicha: http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/770370/jewish/Chassidic-Insights.htm (scroll to verse 22) | http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/15573/jewish/Jacob-and-Esau.htm | http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/2526733/jewish/Chassidic-Dimension-Volume-3-Toldos.htm (second essay)

Answer (score 1):

According to Rav Hirsch on [Toldos 25:23](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8220#v=23&showrashi=true) the two represented two completely opposite and opposing forms of government and culture. As a result, they **could not** leave the other to take control of the world that he preferred. Each one had to insist on governing the world in which he would live according to the principles of his nature.

We can see this in the way the state of Israel is treated in our day and the way the enemies of morality in the United States cannot allow the moral people to live in peace. They are attempting to force everyone else to affirm immorality rather than just attempting to be allowed to live the immoral life style that they prefer.

> Rebecca was informed that she carried two nations in her womb who
>   would represent two forms of social government. The one state would
>   build up its greatness on spirit and morals, on the humane in humans.
>   The other would build up its greatness in cunning and strength. Spirit
>   and strength, morality and violence oppose each other, and indeed from
>   birth onwards will they be in opposition to each other.